# How to turn all pedantic mode for hie in haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-ide-engine

Is it possible to somehow pass --pedantic (as in stack build --pedantic) switch to Haskell-ide-engine? I'd like to see more errors in IDE during compile time as I'm very new to the language, for example for non-exhaustive case patterns.

I cannot find any infos on project page apart from this bug https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine/issues/449 but this does not seem to adress this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I can tell it is not possible to pass compiler or build tool switches in to HIE.  HIE automatically determines your compiler flags based on your build tool and does not have an override mechanism.

Instead you should add the appropriate compiler flags to your build file.  `stack build --pedantic` passes the `-Wall` and `-Werror` flags, so those are the flags you want to add to your build file. That way the flags will always be used by both `stack build` and HIE.

## package.yaml

If you have a `package.yaml` file (the default for most Stack projects) then you should add the following lines to the `ghc-options` section of that file:

```
      - -Wall
      - -Werror
```

Example:

```
name:                project-name
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "githubuser/project-name"
license:             BSD3
author:              "Author name here"
maintainer:          "example@example.com"
copyright:           "2020 Author name here"

description:         Example

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

ghc-options:
- -Wall
- -Werror

executables:
  project-name-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
```

## *package-name*.cabal

If you do *not* have a `package.yaml` file, then add the following lines to all of the `executable` and `library` sections your cabal file:

```
  ghc-options:
    -Wall
    -Werror
```

Example:

```
name:                project-name
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/project-name#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2020 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
extra-source-files:  README.md

executable project-name
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  ghc-options:
    -Wall
    -Werror
```

## More flags

As a side note, GHC's `-Wall` does not enable *all* of the warnings, only most of them.  You might want to add these extra warnings:

```
-Wcompat
-Wincomplete-uni-patterns
-Wincomplete-record-updates
-Wredundant-constraints
-Wpartial-fields
```

See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html for more details.

During development you might want to remove `-Werror` from your `package.yaml` or cabal file.

Comment: I'm just starting with Haskell and I must say I'm really lost with the build systems here. I have started my project with stack new project-name simple and I got a .cabal file and a stack.yaml file both having dependencies inside. Now I would need to add a third project also having dependencies listed (apart from what you suggest). Why is there so much overlap here? Which of the files do I really need?

Comment: I'll give you a quick overview of where this stuff comes from.  Hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: In the beginning there was a tool called Cabal (https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). That's where the `.cabal` files come from. Cabal installs packages from the Hackage repository (https://hackage.haskell.org/). Packages on Hackage often have breaking changes. Care is required when selecting which version of each package to install to ensure that everything is compatible. Cabal tries to do this version selection automatically, but sometimes it fails leaving the programmer to manually adjust version numbers until a working combination is found.

Comment: Stack (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) extends Cabal with new logic for selecting and installing dependencies. That's why Stack still has `.cabal` files. It also adds its own `stack.yaml` file to control where your dependencies are installed from. The idea is that `stack.yaml` describes a curated set of packages that are all mutually compatible. That way you know that you're getting the right version of each dependency (including transitive dependencies), because there's only one version of each package in the curated set.

Comment: As for `package.yaml`, some Haskellers didn't like the old `.cabal` file format, so they created a new YAML based format call Hpack (https://github.com/sol/hpack). `package.yaml` is an Hpack file. Stack has adopted the Hpack format and made it the default for new projects created with `stack new project-name`. If you have a `package.yaml` file then Stack automatically generates a `.cabal` file from it as required. Some Haskellers find `package.yaml` to be worth the complications, but you can do just fine without it.

Comment: Since you created your project with the `simple` template (`stack new project-name simple`), Stack did not create a `package.yaml` file for you. In this case you will have to write the `.cabal` file yourself.

I will amend my answer to include instructions for your cabal file.

Comment: I finally got a change to check this out and this works perfectly. Thanks for your help!